# Função de struct não lê os dados das outras funções

Tags: c

Estou aprendendo funções em struct e a última função do meu código (PassaInfoEMed) não lê os dados das outras, e o erro aparentemente está nessa linha, pois logo que ela é retirada o código compila sem falhas;

```
printf("Ola %s do %i ano, sua media total foi: %0.2f", a.name, a.ano, med);
```

Qual deve ser a maneira correta de chamar os dados de outras funções?

Meu código:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct info{
    char name[255];
    int ano;
    float notas;
}teste;

main(){

teste user[5];

PedeInfo(user);
PedeNotas(user);
PassaInfoEMed(user);
}

void PedeInfo(teste a){
printf("Digite seu primeiro nome: ");
scanf("%s", &a.name);
fflush(stdin);

    printf("Digite o ano que esta cursando: ");
    scanf("%i", &a.ano);
    return a;
}

void PedeNotas(teste *b){
    int i;
    printf("Digite suas cinco notas do semestre: ");
    for (i = 0; i<5; i++){
        scanf("%f", &b[i].notas);
    } 
    return b;
}

// ---- ACHO QUE O ERRO ESTÁ AQUI ---- 
void PassaInfoEMed(teste *c){
    int i;
    float total,med;
    for(i = 0; i<5; i++){
        total += c[i].notas;
    }   med = total / 5;

    printf("Ola %s do %i ano, sua media total foi: %0.2f", a.name, a.ano, med);

    return c;
}
```

Comment: Olá. Primeiramente, sugiro que leia os seguintes artigos: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask e https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Eles o ajudarão a resumir melhor sua pergunta e ser mais objetivo. Você deve focar no problema em questão (por ex, quais erros você está tendo exatamente?) e tentar criar um exemplo mínimo e reproduzível do problema para a comunidade ajudá-lo.

Comment: Na função `PassaInfoEMed` vc recebe um `teste *c`, mas no `printf` vc tenta acessar `a.name`. A variável `a` não existe dentro desta função (não deveria acessar o `c`?)

Comment: já tentei fazer isso mas ele retorna um valor sem sentido nenhum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seu programa tem vários problemas.

Antes de tudo escreva em torno dos dados. O que está tentando fazer? São 5 alunos com uma nota ou um aluno com 5 notas? Ou 5 alunos com 5 notas cada um?

Veja o que usou:

```
typedef struct info
{
    char  name[255];
    int   ano;
    float notas;
} teste;
```

Isso parece descrever 1 aluno, por exemplo

E depois declara

```
    teste user[5];
```

e então são 5 alunos! E `notas` é `float`, uma única nota. Mas em `PedeNotas()` parece que são 5 notas para o mesmo cara. Como vai calcular a média então?

E essa estrutura pode e deve ser anônima.

Pensando em um `Aluno` com 5 notas e em uma `Turma` com até 8 alunos:

```
typedef struct
{
    char     name[25];
    unsigned ano;
    float    notas[5];
    float    media;

}   Aluno;


typedef struct
{
    unsigned N;
    Aluno al[8];

}   Turma;
```

Agora faz mais sentido: uma turma tem `N` alunos. Até 8. Cada aluno tem seu nome, ano, 5 notas e a média. A média nada tem a ver com a `struct`, apenas com as notas.

Ainda escrevendo em torno dos dados: o que é `PedeInfo()`? Deve ler um único aluno e claro que isso inclui as notas. Então deve retornar o que? Um `Aluno`.

Vou deixar um **exemplo** simples para você ver como acessar essas coisas. Deixei um campo com a média na estrutura, é só um exemplo.

Ao ler o aluno a função chama a outra que pede as notas --- `PedeNotas()` ---  e essa já pode retornar a média.

É claro que vai querer ter uma função `Mostra()` para mostrar os dados de um aluno...

#### `main()` no exemplo

```
int main(void)
{
    Turma t1;
    t1.al[0] = PedeInfo();
    Mostra(&t1.al[0]);
}
```

Assim `main()` é simples de ler: declara uma turma, usa `PedeInfo()` para preencher um dos 8 alunos, no caso o primeiro. E mostra na tela os dados.

**Eis a saída do exemplo**

```
Digite seu primeiro nome: Stack
Digite o ano que esta cursando: 3

Digite suas cinco notas do semestre: 1 2 3 4 5

        Aluno:  Stack [Ano: 3]
        Notas:   1.00   2.00   3.00   4.00   5.00  Media:   3.00
```

E o código todo

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct
{
    char     name[25];
    unsigned ano;
    float    nota[5];
    float    media;

}   Aluno;

typedef struct 
{
    unsigned N;
    Aluno al[8];

}   Turma;

int   Mostra(Aluno*);
Aluno PedeInfo();
float PedeNotas(float[]);

int main(void)
{
    Turma t1;
    t1.al[0] = PedeInfo();
    Mostra(&t1.al[0]);
}

int Mostra(Aluno* al)
{
    printf("\n\tAluno:\t%s [Ano: %d]\n\tNotas: ", al->name, al->ano);
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i += 1)
        printf("%6.2f ", al->nota[i]);
    printf(" Media: %6.2f\n\n", al->media);
    return 0; // podia retornar algum erro 
};

Aluno PedeInfo()
{
    Aluno um;
    printf("Digite seu primeiro nome: ");
    scanf("%s", &um.name);

    printf("Digite o ano que esta cursando: ");
    scanf("%i", &um.ano);

    um.media = PedeNotas(um.nota);
    return um;
}

float PedeNotas(float nota[])
{
    printf("\nDigite suas cinco notas do semestre: ");
    int n = scanf(
        "%f %f %f %f %f", &nota[0], &nota[1],
        &nota[2], &nota[3], &nota[4]);

    if (n != 5)
    {
        printf("\nerro! Nao leu todas as notas\n");
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i += 1) nota[i] = 0.;
        return 0.;
    };

    // leu as notas: calcula e retorna a media
    float soma = 0.;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i += 1) soma+= nota[i];
    soma /= 5;
    return soma;
}
```

Não estou usando a turma como tal. É apenas um exemplo de como compor os dados.